# Redirect pages of root folder to index and pages of subfolder to index of subfolder

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

As the title says, I have the root directory that contains pages and I have another directory that it's called mobile.

I would like the pages that are inside the root directory to be all redirected to index.php in root, as for the mobile directory I want all the pages inside it to be redirected to the other index.php that is inside /mobile

I have tried multiple times but it seems that sometimes I can only get one folder working at a time.

Any help would be much appreciated !

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this code both in site root .htaccess and `mobile/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That worked like a charm. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Nginx. ;)

Example.

```
location ~ ^/lol/index.php$
{
    alias /var/www/abc/lol/index.php;
}

location ~ ^/lol/
{
    return 302 https://example.org/lol/index.php;
}

location ~ ^/index.php$
{
    alias /var/www/abc/index.php;
}

location ~ ^/?
{
    return 302 https://example.org/index.php;
}
```

Skills required: RegEx (`~`).

The HTTP status code 302 causes your browser to switch to this page. I don't like 301 so much when developing, because your browser remembers the redirects or caches them.

With the location blocks it depends of course also on the order.

Comment: That's realy good to know. Can you tell me where do we add this code ? is it in php.ini file ? or elsewhere ?

Comment: Nginx instead of Apache.